# For loop in lambda with data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, lambda

I have a data frame `df_android['App']` which includes English and non-English names. I would like to get rid of those that are non-English. 
The idea is to use a system of numbers that represent letters. The numbers above 127 are not English signs.

I have tried to implement it in lambda but I don't know how to split each name in `df_android['App']` into letters:

```
for app in df_android['App']:
    for letter in app:
        letter = ord(letter)

df_android['Lang'] = df_android['App'].apply(lambda x: 'English' if letter < 127 else 'non-English')
```

How can I figure out which letter is English/non-English and apply this knowledge into a new column?

Example:

[image]

Comment: `.apply(lambda x: 'English' if all(letter < 127 for word in x for letter in word) else 'non-English')`

Comment: Can you add some data sample and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael I have added the example :)

Comment: @NorahJones - OK, can you create some sample data in text, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - e.g. 3 rows in column `App`? [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `[صور حرف H, Easy Origami Ideas, Tattoo Name On My Photo Editor]`
Is this sufficient?

Comment: Thanks @splash58! I just needed to do `ord(letter)` since it can't understand otherwise :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer:
`df_android['Lang'] = df_android['App'].apply(lambda x: 'English' if all(ord(letter) < 127 for word in x for letter in word) else 'non-English')`